# Ruby on rails- how to put a user id in a status update treehouse challenge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a social network on the course that treehouse.com provide. It uses ruby on rails.

I am stuck at the minute because when I click post status I get this message. I'm trying to replace just any name with the user id. I have added all the correct things treehouse tell you to do but I get this error:

NoMethodError in Statuses#show

Showing /Users/lewisfrost/frostbook/app/views/statuses/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `first_name' for 13:Fixnum

Extracted source (around line #5):

5:   <%= @status.user_id.first_name %>

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@status.user_id` is just a number. User `@status.user` instead.

```
<%= @status.user.first_name if @status.user %>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I just tried it but it still doesn't work! I now get the same sort of thing:
NoMethodError in Statuses#show

Showing /Users/lewisfrost/frostbook/app/views/statuses/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
5: <%= @status.user.first_name %>

Comment: That means your Status has no user associated with it, it means the data is wrong. Insert an if statement, to prevent that appearing.

Answer (score 1):

In your Model Statuses you have write Statuses - User Relation? 
LIke

```
class Statuses 
  belongs_to :user
....
end
```

and now you can type

> @status.user.first_name

Comment: Yes, I have followed everything correctly, it just doesn't seem to work!

Comment: In Your statuses you have create(and migrate) field with name user_id ?